# Why don't Federal Reserve Notes pay for purchases?

Tags: payment, purchase, federal-reserve

What constitutes true payment if a Federal Reserve Note is NOT payment?

Ounces of gold? Anything I deem value in agreement with another party?

Comment: 1) Why do you think American currency is not payment? It sounds like you've been listening to conspiracy theorists. 2) If you're not going to use currency, it's entirely up to you to negotiate the terms of the transaction. 3) This is pretty far outside the usual definition of "personal finance", and is likely to be closed.

Comment: There are barter laws in the US where anything (including services) can be used as payment if both parties agree. But it's not clear what you're actually asking  what do you mean by "Federal Reserve Note is NOT payment"?

Answer (score 1):

Do you (potentially unknowingly) refer to section 16 of the Federal Reserve Act which formalizes the promise by the United States to pay the stated face amount of the note to the bearer on demand in "lawful money."?

Back in the days, this meant mainly gold. Nowadays, what is a Federal reserve note is quite interesting from a legal standpoint. In the 1974 case Milam v. U.S., 524 F.2d 629 (9th Cir. 1974), a person called Milam,

> sought to require the Federal Reserve Board to redeem a $50 Federal
> Reserve note in gold or silver. The Ninth Circuit, noting that this
> matter had been put to rest by the U.S. Supreme Court nearly a century
> before (in Juilliard v. Greenman, 110 U.S. 421 (1884)), disagreed with
> Milam's contentions. The court stated: "While we agree that golden
> eagles, double eagles and silver dollars were lovely to look at and
> delightful to hold, we must at the same time recognize that time
> marches on. . . . [Milam] is entitled to redeem his [Federal Reserve]
> note, but not in precious metal." In other words, a holder of a
> Federal Reserve note who presents it for redemption in lawful money is
> likely to receive in exchange lawful money in the form of another
> Federal Reserve note.

Some more details can be found in [The Fed Notes: A Lawyer's Perspective on U.S. Payment System Evolution and Money in the Digital Age](https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/notes/feds-notes/a-lawyers-perspective-on-us-payment-system-evolution-and-money-in-the-digital-age-20220204.html#:%7E:text=A%20Federal%20Reserve%20note%20is,of%20the%20Federal%20Reserve%20Act.).

Comment: lawful money is coins. You can redeem the federal reserve notes for coins (which is the actual money minted by the US treasury). They used to be silver/gold, but not anymore.

Comment: @littleadv if I show up at the Federal Reserve with a million dollars in cash, given the largest coin in common circulation is 50 cents, will they happily return me 2 million coins? I doubt it. Why don't you think the notes are also lawful money?

Comment: @user253751 Yes. And the largest coin in circulation is $1 AFAIK. The notes are *not* lawful money, they're legal tender. But they're obligations, not money. See 12 USC 411.

Comment: Of course _unless_ you are trying to redeem them at the federal reserve, that distinction makes no practical difference that I can see... except to give the sovereign citizen whackos another quibble to build conspiracy theories around. Which I am guessing is the community the "true payment" language came from; it sounds like one of their formulations.